# Owl Carousel JS return to first image

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have an OwlCarousel with nav links within the first slide, is there a way to make the carousel return to the first slide after an event, be it a timer, or when the mouse moves out of the carousel?
Is it also possible to trigger the carousel with mousing over a link rather than clicking it?

Code snippet:

```
            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide0">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#slide1">1</a></li><br/>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#slide2">2</a></li><br/>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#slide3">3</a></li><br/>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#silde4">4</a></li><br/>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#slide5">5</a></li><br/>
                        <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#slide6">6</a></li><br/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide1">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide2">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide3">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide4">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide5">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="item" data-hash="slide6">
                    //some image
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [owlCarousel's docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html#to-owl-carousel) you can use the `to.owl.carousel` function to slide to specific position.

Here is an example for both - going to the first slide (slides numbering starts with 0) and hover on the `li` elements to go to a specific slide on hover.

```js
var owl;
$(document).ready(function(){
  owl = $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({items:1});
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0, 400]);
  });
  
  $('#ul1 li').hover(function() {
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [parseInt($(this).text()) - 1, 400]);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 120px;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Set up your HTML -->

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"> slide1 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide2 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide3 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide4 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide5 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide6 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide7 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide8 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide9 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide10 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide11 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide12 </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Go to first</button>
<ul id="ul1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```